# Making a shape in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to make this shape in CSS?

[image]

If so, specify how? Please be descriptive and add comments so other's can also benefit by this!

Comment: You can also benefit other users by showing what have you tried.

Comment: @Hassan see my answer for shape you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many online tutorials available to making a shape using CSS3. However I made a Demo for you..

CSS should be like this..

```
div{
border:20px solid red; 
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
<div></div>
```

Here is the Demo for you. http://jsbin.com/zevavica/1/

Comment: Can you explain how you did it?

Comment: I've updated the example for you by changing colors, Hope this way you can understand the how border effect works. check the above Demo link or click her.. `http://jsbin.com/zevavica/1/`

Comment: This is the answer, ticked!

Answer (score 2):

Shapes are possible in CSS, and there is lot of online resources that have samples and tutorials on how to make them.

Here is one of them: http://www.css3shapes.com/

I would recommend that you do little research on Google, you can find everything you need there.

Best of luck!

Comment: You are welcome Hassan, best of luck!

Comment: An upvote will be good mate!

Answer (score 2):

**Sample:**

HTML

```
<div id='trapezoid'></div>
```

CSS

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

I hope this helps you.
Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div in your HTML document and apply the below CSS to it.

```
#trapezoid {
    border-top: 100px solid grey;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shape you want (not exactly but you can set dimensions accordingly)

**CSS:**

```
#holder {
    background: #EEF3FA;
    height:40px;
    width: 340px;
}
#shape {
    width: 300px;
    border-top: 20px solid #8D8D8D;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Above one works, but I'll take a look at this!

Comment: oml cant stop laughing, same as the image! good job!

Comment: An upvote will be good mate!